# JVm with version 1.6 in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

i am  download the eclipse in my computer with system 32 bit but when i run the eclipse.exe appear this message (( version 1.2.1 of the JVM is not suitable for this product , version 1.6 or greater is required )) 
i cant find this version
any help pleas 
thanks

Comment: You mention 32-bit. Is the installed JRE/JDK also 32-bit? They have to match.

Comment: what's your JDK version? you can install the latest JDK from Oracle's website

Answer (score 1):

Did you download a recent version JDK(Java Development Kit) or JRE already? If not, download and install it first:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

If you already did, then make sure `JAVA_HOME` is set properly:

1. Right-click the **My Computer** icon on
2. your desktop and select **Properties**.
3. Click the **Advanced** tab. Click the
4. **Environment Variables** button. Under **System Variables**, find `JAVA_HOME`.
5. Enter the variable name as **JAVA_HOME**.
6. Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.
7. Click **OK**.
8. Click **Apply Changes**.